# Prove the inequality in Banach space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, inequality, banach-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $X$ such that, for some $x \in X$,

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ell(x_n) = \ell(x) \text{  for all bounded linear functional } \ell : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.
$$
I'm trying to show that $ \|x \| \leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty } \|x_n\|$.

By using definition of norm of linear functional, we can get two inequality.

$\| \ell(x_n) \| \leq \| \ell \| \|x_n\|$, $\| \ell(x) \| \leq \| \ell \| \|x\|$.

We know that $\ell(x_n) \rightarrow \ell(x)$, so $\|\ell(x) \| \leq \|\ell\| \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|x_n\|$.

Do I need to show that $\|x \| \leq \frac{\|\ell(x)\|}{\|\ell\|}$ to solve this problem?

I think I do not use the conditions(Banach space or *all bounded linear functional) appropriately.

Comment: There exists an $\ell$ with $\ell(x)=\|x\|$ and $\|\ell\| \leq 1$ This is a standard application of Hahn Banach Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks. I understand that $\ell(x) = \|x\|$ makes $\|x\| = \frac{\| \ell(x)\|}{\| \ell \|} \leq \liminf \|x_n\|$. But I'm confused that which part do I use the Hahn Banach Theorem. Why do I need a extension of bounded linear functional (Because Hahn Banach Theorem is theorem about extension of bounded linear functional in subspace)? I think $\ell(x) = \|x \| $ makes a complete solution.